# How to dismiss PopupWindow with touch outside when its mFocusable set false?

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I have a `PopupWindow` and it is `setFocusable(false)`, I want to dismiss it when touch outside, and it is already `setOutsideTouchable(true)`, but with the `setFocusable(false)` it doesn't work, how can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

All the properties being set to my `PopupWindow` are as follows:

```
popUpWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(xx);
popUpWindow.setTouchable(true);
popUpWindow.setFocusable(false);
popUpWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
popUpWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
popUpWindow.update();
```

---

update:

I was wrong, the `PopupWindow` dismissed, but some other code make it show.

Comment: why not just setFocusable to true.that kind of a contradiction somewhat.

Comment: @CaspainCaldion setFoucusable to false, it someone to solve a bug, and I shall bypass to change it to true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it may work

```
// Removes default background.
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
myPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Alternatively:

```
myPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Not sure what the differences are, but the ListPopupWindow source code actually uses the latter when it's modality is set to true with setModal, so at least the Android developers consider this a viable approach, and it's only one line.

BTW, Don't use BitmapDrawable deprecated constructor, use this **new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent)** to replace default background.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: @twlkyao can you post your popup window initialisation including all property you are setting up ? and what's your actual purpose to make it focusable false ?

Comment: I was wrong, it dismissed, but somewhere make it show.